# python beautiful soup get name of all classes inside HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

With python and BS4 I am trying to get the names of all the classes inside a tag.

So far my code is

```
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            for ele in cols:
                print ele.find_all('mark')

print result is [<mark class="footer"></mark>]
```

how can I get class name out of it with beautful soup. (I need the names of classes for later to do styling)

thank you

Comment: Please remove the solution from the question and provide it as an answer. Or just accept the Md. Mohsin answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is as simple as mentioned in your question then just do,

```
print ele.find_all('mark')[0]['class']
```

However, if you want to filter elements in two parts --- 1. with class and 2. without classes then you may refer to this [link](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) of bs4 documentation.

Hope that helps :-)