# Is there a way to extract all the class name from an HTML file using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<tr id="section_1asd8aa" class="main">
<td class="header">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;>DUMMY TEXT<a href="#">browser.</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</td></tr>
```

Above is a sample html and I want to extract all the class names from the html file.
Output:'{ "c1":"main","c2":"header"}'

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: What are `c1`, `c2` here? Are they important?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov so far I am able to read the html, I can fetch each html tags but that's not what I am looking far

Comment: @Psidom I am expecting value to be returned in a json format so c1 and c2 are just an example.

Comment: add your code sample

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python beautiful soup get name of all classes inside HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647266/python-beautiful-soup-get-name-of-all-classes-inside-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find_all` to get a set of nodes, then loop through the set of nodes and check if the node has `class` attribute, if it has, return the class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<tr id="section_1asd8aa" class="main">
<td class="header">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;>DUMMY TEXT<a href="#">browser.</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</td></tr>""", "html.parser")
```

To get a list of class names:

```
lst = [node['class'] for node in soup.find_all() if node.has_attr('class')]
lst
# [['main'], ['header']]
```

Convert the list to a dictionary:

```
{"c"+str(i): v  for i, v in enumerate(lst)}
# {'c0': ['main'], 'c1': ['header']}
```

Notice the classes are wrapped in a list because some class can have multiple values. You can join the list as a single string if that's desired.

```
{"c"+str(i): " ".join(v)  for i, v in enumerate(lst)}
# {'c0': 'main', 'c1': 'header'}
```